Wordpress PHP Author Dropdown Selection
I have a PHP snippet that is partially working. It's a dropdown menu that will redirect to the author page when selected. But, if I use the same snippet on the author's page (to view another author), the page reloads and some extra code is added to the url.
Note that my authors pages are subcategories of the category author, so the urls look like /author/john-smith
Here's the code I'm using (patched together from various snips I found)
<select class="select-css"  name="author-dropdown" id="author-dropdown--1" onchange="document.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
<option value=""><?php echo esc_attr( __( 'CONTRIBUTORS' ) ); ?></option> 
<?php 
// loop through the users
$users = get_users('role=author');
foreach ($users as $user) 
{
    if(count_user_posts( $user->id ) >0)
    {
    // We need to add our url to the authors page
    echo '<option value="'.get_author_posts_url( $user->id ).'">';
    // Display name of the author you could use another like nice_name
    echo $user->display_name;
    echo '</option>'; 

    } 
}
?>
</select>

I've tried adding /author/ to the echo, but I don't know PHP well enough to really understand how to fix this. Anyone have any ideas?`
A sample of the code taken from the author page source:


<div class="et_pb_text_inner"><select class="select-css" name="author-dropdown" id="author-dropdown--1" onchange="document.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
<option value="">CONTRIBUTORS</option> 
<option value="https://active-staging.mysite.com/author/anil-daka/?mab_v3=18258">Aaron Socker</option>
<option value="https://active-staging.mysite.com/author/anil-daka/?mab_v3=18258">Aden Gebeyehu</option>
    </select></div>




It's a bit tricky to determine the exact problem from the snippet you've provided, or what the exact problem is. You say that when using this code on the Author's page, the page immediately reloads and parameters are added to the URL? If that is the case, please add the full URL (with the extra info) to your problem statement, this will definitely help. Also, do you get any errors in console? Those would be helpful as well. Aside from that, the more we see, the better we can diagnose. Showing the full code (minus unnecessary html/css) of the Author page would definitely help.

I did a little more investigating and the extra code added to the url is ?mab_v3, which is Microsofe Azure Backup 3, which is really strange.

I'm afraid my knowledge of the Wordpress ecosystem is too limited to help in this regard, I'm not sure where those extra URL params could come from, I'm sorry.
